# Thanos in Guardians of the Galaxy 2 jump gate scene?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2

I watched *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol 2* a few days ago and I thought I saw Thanos (or someone like him) in the Rocket and Yondu jump scene, close to the beginning of the scene, before the Stan Lee cameo.

It looked like he was fighting someone.

I doubt I'll be watching the movie again, so can someone please put my hypothesis to rest?

Comment: James Gunn has said that [Thanos was not going to be in Vol 2](http://www.cinemablend.com/news/1621760/why-thanos-isnt-in-guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2-according-to-james-gunn)

Comment: there is a scene with several blue-skinned aliens on it, but they're not Thanos, is that what you're thinking of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your description only matches with this scene:

[image]

Where two rock like creatures are fighting.

And they match with marvel comics race [Kronans](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Kronans).

And as mentioned by phantom42 [in comment](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72895/thanos-in-guardians-of-the-galaxy-2-jump-gate-scene#comment118096_72895), Thanos is not in the film:

> James Gunn: It's about two sisters. It's not about the sisters and their father. It's about two sisters, and what were the sisters' problems with each other. ... It really isn't about Thanos. 
>   - [cinemablend.com](http://www.cinemablend.com/news/1621760/why-thanos-isnt-in-guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2-according-to-james-gunn)

Answer (score -2):

It does look like Thanos. But he is the one on the floor. Might the movie be playing homage to when Thanos fought Champion in the Thanos Quest story arc??[image]