# What worlds do Rocket and Yondu jump past?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2

In [Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3896198/?ref_=tttr_tr_tt), **Rocket** and **Yondu** jump past several worlds as they travel back to the rest of the team.

One of the scenes is memorable for featuring **Stan Lee**'s cameo, surrounded by what appear to be **Watchers**. But there seems to be a few other areas that they jump through and creatures that are seen that I didn't recognize.

What worlds and creatures do **Rocket** and **Yondu** jump past?

Comment: Also, cross-site related Q: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159056/which-if-any-planets-and-characters-are-known-during-the-space-hop-scene

Comment: One of the first they go through has a couple giants (frost giants on Jotunheim?) fighting, anyone catch a close glimpse of that?

Comment: @Ross they are Kronans

Comment: There was def a pink gelatin like area they burst thru as well. It made me wonder were they jumping thru dimensions or just thru spacial locations.

Answer (score 10):

There were only two prominent places I can briefly remember:

One with two giant creatures fighting

[image]

Which are apparently belongs to [Kronans](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Kronans) race which are going to part of upcoming film Thor: Ragnarok and seems like a nod to it. Also covered in [my other answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/73017/1190) to a related question.

Second which you mentioned in question itself, Stan Lee talking to disinterested  watchers about his adventures (marvel film cameos)

[image][image]

Which was more of a joke to the fan theory of Stan Lee being Watcher.

Rest they were just jumping from hexagonal doorways to colourful places and making pinball sound.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In my memory there were more than 2 (bad memory)

Comment: I think Lee's cameo was confirmation of the theory that he is Uatu or a watcher, not a joke. On another note, anyone else think that watcher looks like Arturo Castro?